# Visual Studio 2017 SQL : Can't Add Table Data

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database

[image]

As shown in the image, I can't seem to alter the value of cells in the table. I just right clicked the table from the Server Explorer and pressed Show Table Data. The tooltip over the error message says something along the lines "The value in this cell has changed. Press ESC to revert it back to the previous value of NULL." I can't leave the tab until i revert the values back to NULL.

Comment: You either commit (press enter), cancel (press ESC) or set all fields to null. There's no problem here

Answer (score 0):

After entering values for a row click on the next row and save your table. It should work.